# С чего стоит начать разработку CMS?

Tags: php, cms, css, javascript

После изучения соответствующих технологий, естественно.
С паттернов проектирования, разработки архитектуры (кстати чего можно почитать полезного по этому поводу?), с определения задачи и структурных особенностей? Дабы не упустить чего-нибудь, когда будет написано 80% всего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с изучения уже существующих CMS, внятного и убедительного ответа на вопрос «зачем нужна ещё одна и чем она лучше уже существующих?» и позиционирования новой CMS на рынке.

Answer (score 1):

Написание кода - самая маловажная деталь в таких продуктах. Гораздо важней сесть и подумать, создать прочную, максимально легкорасширяемую архитектуру (хотя бы на бумаге).

Answer (score 0):

> После изучения соответствующих
> технологий, естественно. С паттернов
> проектирования, разработки архитектуры
> (кстати чего можно почитать полезного
> по этому поводу?), с определения
> задачи и структурных особенностей?

Я один в вопросе увидел ЭТО

> я тут почитал и понял что выучил, но выучил не все, точнее не учил, а как я выразился почитал. дайте почитать то чего еще я не указал в вопросе.

Везде знаки вопросов! С таким подходом нужно просто серфить инет и дальше этого серфа не уходить в изучение weba.

Answer (score 0):

1. написать сайт с динамическим контентом
2. написать там админку
   цмска готова =)
3. хочется добавить возможность добавления плагинов
4. или переписать сайт опять (или сделать хороший рефакторинг) и правильный, т.е. с хорошими интерфейсами
5. или все это прелусмотреть сразу
6. или забить и пользоваться готовым велосипедом